# VSCode single to double quote automatic replace

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I execute a `Format Document` command on a Vue Component.vue file VSCode replace all single quoted string with double quoted string.

In my specific case this rule conflicts with electron-vue lint configuration that require singlequote.

I don't have prettier extensions installed (no `prettier.singleQuote` in my setting)

How to customize VSCode to avoid this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code Auto Indent / Code Formatting changes single quotation marks to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091719/vs-code-auto-indent-code-formatting-changes-single-quotation-marks-to-double)

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64749368/984471

Comment: Also related: [Visual Studio Code - Adjust import quotation setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952453/visual-studio-code-adjust-import-quotation-setting)

Comment: After reading through the answers here (including the accepted one) what actually worked for me was creating a .prettierrc.json and adding the {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "jsxSingleQuote": true
}
 to it. I already had these settings in the user settings in VSCode but they had no effect. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 271, accepted):

I dont have `prettier` extension installed, but after reading the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091719/vs-code-auto-indent-code-formatting-changes-single-quotation-marks-to-double) answer I've added from scratch in my User Setting (`UserSetting.json`, Ctrl+, shortcut):

```json
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

A part a green warning (`Unknown configuration setting`) the single quotes are no more replaced.

I suspect that the prettier extension is not visible but is embedded inside the [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) extension.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to use `vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions` instead. See [https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/formatting.html#settings](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/formatting.html#settings).

Comment: After opening the quick search, type ">user settings" and click "Preferences: Open User Settings". In the search box of your preferences, type "prettier.singleQuote" and click the checkbox for prettier single quote.

Comment: This didn't work for me, `quote_type = single` in `[*.myDesiredFileExtension]` section within `.editorconfig` file, was the solution.

Comment: `html.completion.attributeDefaultValue: "singlequotes"`

After such a long struggling, I'll add my comment here to the top answer. The problem is, there is additional feature and additional setting that does not respect .editor config or prettier. It is 

`html.completion.attributeDefaultValue: "singlequotes"`

I was testing HTML with adding new attribute, and even with all plugins disabled, it still adds double quote no matter what. This is VSCode feature, and it have separate settins, please, add this to your settings and enjoy!
Consider to add this to response,

Answer (score 196):

Well, like the guy (@user2982122) mentioned but instead of **File** go to **Code** -> Preferences -> Settings, then look for **Quote**, select **Prettier** and check both boxes

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have to reload these settings for them to take effect? I have them both checked, but when I save my .jsx file the double quotes don't change to single.

Comment: That is weird, I am using this version: Release 1.14 build 1.14.0-17740

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.  (This should have been the default setting ...)

Comment: God bless you, this detail was killing me.

Comment: @Woodchuck, I ran into the same issue. It started working for me after restarting the VS Code.

Answer (score 141):

For projects that use `.editorconfig` file by default. The formatter will ignore the rules in the settings and use the rules in `.editorconfig`, then you can either:

- Remove `.editorconfig` file, and use your VSCode settings.
- Add `quote_type = single` to the `.editorconfig` file regarding your file type. You can also set `quote_type` value to `double` or `auto`.

Comment: I did this and it didn't work regardless if I installed editorconfig globally or I try to sue the editorconfig for VS Code. :(

Comment: Thanks, my Angular app do use `.editorconfig` by default (didn't know that) and your solution fixed my problem

Comment: please consider: you may not delete `.editorconfig` if it is a common versioned project

Comment: Note: You should restart VSCode to apply these changes.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm after adding `quote_type = single` in my vue app (still keep `.editorconfig`)

Answer (score 89):

It looks like it is a bug open for this issue: [Prettier Bug](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/206)

**None of above solution worked for me.**
The only thing that worked was, adding this line of code in package.json:

```
"prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true
  },
```

Comment: Unbelievably, Dec 2020, this is still the only thing that work for me as well!

Comment: Mar 2021 now and this is still the only solution work for me

Comment: April 2021, only thing that worked, it is ridiculous that we need to change package.json for a local extension

Comment: 2022 and using Vue 3, only this one worked for me.

Comment: I created a project by vite and only your solution work for me

Comment: You can easier do oneliner: `"prettier.singleQuote": true`

Comment: this is 2023 and this answer is working fine

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in 2024 and using Angular

Answer (score 74):

At the time of writing (June 2022):

please consider that `.editorconfig` overwrites every other configuration at the end, find the file (most probably on the root of your project), edit it and add the following:

```
[*]
quote_type = single
```

Comment: This is the right one!

Comment: Open the **Output** tab, if this message shows: `Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used`, then this answer is the solution.

Comment: FYI, `quote_type` is a proposal that is not intended to be implemented by EditorConfig. See [here](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#ideas-for-domain-specific-properties).

Answer (score 47):

From the vuejs/vetur issue page [https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/986#](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/986#issuecomment-441918550)
This solution worked for me.

In VSCodes `settings.json` file add this entry

```
"vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    "prettier": {
        "singleQuote": true
    }
},
```

Answer (score 34):

Install prettier extension and paste below code in your VSCode `settings.json` file

```
 "prettier.useEditorConfig": false,
 "prettier.singleQuote": true
```

this will ignore your `.editorconfig` file setting.

Comment: works if you want all of your other settings ruined.

Comment: this comment here is underated

Answer (score 20):

What worked for me was setting up the `.prettierrc.json` config file. Put it to the root of your project with a sample config like this:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "arrowParens": "always"
}
```

After triggering the Format Document command, all works just as expected.

***Side note**: What comes as a bonus with this solution is that each team member gets the same formatting outputs thanks to the present config file.*

Comment: Worked for me and instead I included the command I want within `.prettierrc.js`

Answer (score 15):

Correct solution :

I add .prettierrc.js file in my main root project
and write

```
module.exports = {
    singleQuote: true
  };
```

Comment: I tried this but it throws an error: "ESLint: Failed to load config "defaults/configurations/eslint" to extend from." Best would be to add this in package.json. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59137494/9294131)

Comment: did you put your .prettierrc.js file in the root of the project ?

Answer (score 14):

For newbies like me:

From the menu Nav bar at the top:  Select File -> Preferences -> Settings.
In the search text box, type in Quote
In the filtered list that appears below, look for the gear icon and next to it -  "Prettier". Click on check box to enable "Prettier: Single Quote"

Answer (score 11):

Try one of these solutions

1. In vscode settings.json file add this entry
   `"prettier.singleQuote": true`
2. In vscode if you have `.editorconfig` file, add this line under the root [*] symbol `quote_type = single`
3. In vscode if you have `.prettierrc` file, add this line

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
        "prettier": {
            "singleQuote": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: second option worked, unfortunately the other answers in this page didn't work

Answer (score 11):

First, install the **Prettier** extension. Create a **.prettierrc** configuration file at the root of your project. And add config like below:

> ```
> {
>   "trailingComma": "es5",
>   "singleQuote": true,
>   "jsxSingleQuote": true,
>   "printWidth": 100,
>   "tabWidth": 2,
>   "semi": true,
>   "endOfLine": "auto"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 10):

```
quote_type = single
```

add this inside .editorconfig

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: https://EditorConfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
insert_final_newline = false
quote_type = single
```

Answer (score 10):

After struggling with the issue I found a useful tool. If you click on the `Prettier` word in the right lower corner you will get the `Output` window opened. In that window once you run formatting (in my case it is `Alt + Shift + F`) you will see all the configurations which prettier will use to format the document. So, we can clearly see that specifying the `prettier` in the `prettier.singleQuote` is wrong. It should just be `singleQuote`. Hence, having the `.prettierrc` file in my user root folder with the following contents produced the desired result:

```
{
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "useEditorConfig": false,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

Also, make sure that you have the `Prettier` extension installed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue in vscode. Just create a **.prettierrc** file in your root directory and add the following json.
**For single quotes add:**

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

**For double quotes add:**

```
  {
      "singleQuote": false
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

in .prettierrc add

```json
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As noted by @attdona the Vetur extension includes prettier.

While you can change the prettier settings, as per the accepted answer, you can also change the formatter for specific regions of a vue component.

Here, for example, I've set Vetur to use the vscode-typescript formatter as it uses single quotes by default:

[image: vscode vetur settings]

Answer (score 7):

I'm using typescript, for me it got resolved with checking "Tslint integration" flag under prettier settings (in vscode preferences):

[image: vscode settings for prettier, fixing double quote auto formatting issue]

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21424#issuecomment-282524286 - this is when/where it went into VSCode

Answer (score 7):

There only solution that worked for me:
and only for Angular Projects:

Just go into your project ".editorconfig" file and paste 'quote_type = single'.
Hope it should work for you as well.

Comment: i needed this solution specifically for an angular project as well, all other chnages to prettier settings did not work.

Answer (score 7):

> It works for me to check **single quote** in Prettier as well
>   tslint.autoFixOnSave as **true**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the problem was in the escaping `\` character inside the string:

```
message = 'Error argument is not an object, it\'s ' + typeof error
```

Turning on the [`avoidEscape`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes#avoidescape) option and using double quotes for that string solved the problem:

```
message = "Error argument is not an object, it's " + typeof error
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  rules : {
    // Other rules...
    'quotes' : ['error', 'single', {'avoidEscape' : true}],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I added file called `.prettierrc` in my project folder.
File content:

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
        "prettier": {
            "singleQuote": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this in settings.json

```
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
```

Answer (score 4):

go to  **Settings**, then look for *Quote Double*, and select  **JavaScript Preferences**

[image]

or add this to VS **settings.json**

```
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double"
```

or

```
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BriteSnow.vscode-toggle-quotes

cmd ' (ctrl ' on win/Linux) will cycle among ' " `

Answer (score 3):

For JSX use:

```
{"jsxSingleQuote": false}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for me both options solved the issue:

1. By adding inside the .prettierrc -   "singleQuote": true
2. Or by adding following inside the package.json ->
   "prettier": {
   "singleQuote": true
   }

Though I tried also adding `.prettierrc.js` and have following

module.exports = {
singleQuote: true
};

This didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :
try right click on the current document
and choose "format document with " ,
and choose your own format extension for the document.
:)

Comment: This worked for me. I had correct prettier settings and the correct entries in .editorconfig but double quotes were not replaced with single ones on save. I fight clicked and chose Format Document With... and setup the default formatter from the two choices. Started working after that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of issues controlling linting and prettier formating. I had rules for eslint on for prettier like

```
"prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      { "singleQuote": true, "trailingComma": "none" }
    ],
```

and rules inside .prettierrc file

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2
}
```

But my .prettierrc file was not getting processed. My fix was installing prettier as a package on dev dependency. So the solution that worked for me was installing all these packages `eslint-config-prettier` `eslint-plugin-prettier` and `prettier`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a YAML plugin, it also has a single/double quote option that was tripping me up. Cheers.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

"prettier": {
"singleQuote": true
},

This line of code save my hours.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve it is by disabling all formatting rules in eslint by installing
`npm i -D eslint-config-prettier`  then adding "prettier" at the end of extends array of `eslint` config file

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
    'airbnb-typescript/base',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'prettier',

  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  root: true,
};
```

And then made prettier as my default formatter [image]

Answer (score 0):

wow. none of the above worked.
any text with apostrophe, when i type in `'bob\'s Burgers'` , on save, turns into `"bob's burgers"`, then eslint would complain. Prettier was the culprit. prettier would auto double quote, causing eslint to error.

```
{
  ...
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true,
}
```

What worked for me: disable prettier, and let eslint and VScode to all the work.

1. go to ctrl +p.
2. go to "> settings.json"
   here's my settings.json

```
{
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript"
  ],
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  },
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "workbench.tree.indent": 15,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.foldingMaximumRegions": 50000,
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/*.bundle": true,
    "**/*.bundle.map": true,
    "**/dist": true,
    "**/mobile-gifts": true
  },
  "[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/mobile-gifts": true
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

and my eslintrc.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", { max: 1, maxBOF: 0, maxEOF: 0 }],
    indent: ["error", 2],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    camelcase: "off",
    "spaced-comment": "error",
    quotes: "off",
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
    semi: ["error", "never"],
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `.eslintrc`, `.prettier.js` and **VS Prettier - Code Formatter Extension**.

**Step 1:** With the **VS Prettier - Code Formatter Extension**, you can double check your if your VS Code configurations are defaulting/overriding your settings.

[image: VS Code Extension Output]

**Step 2:** In my case, I updated the **Workspace VS Config Path** - by targeting the prettier configuration file.

[image: VS Config Path Workspace Settings]

**Step 3:** I had to double check that my configuration files were named properly.

**Prettier**
[image: Prettier supports configuration files]

**Source:** *https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html*

**ESLint**
[image: ESLint supports configuration files]

**Source:**
*https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats*