# VSCode Format on Save changes quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

When I save I the quotes are changing from backticks -> `´` <- (this one the other way around) to `"`.

From:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
```

to

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Gatsby Default Starter",
    description:
      "Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.",
    author: "@gatsbyjs",
  },
```

How can I prevent that?

I use prettier and eslint with defaults

Comment: `"prettier.singleQuote": true` ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866406/2312051

Comment: not working: its overwriting the backticks to singlequotes

Comment: hmm... I disabled now prettier nothing changed, then I disabled eslint. after disabling eslint, the error did not appear. so it has to do with eslint

Comment: suppose you could use `"prettier.singleQuote": false`

Comment: you could also use 
`"prettier.quoteProps": "as-needed"`

Comment: my current prettier options:
`{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "parser": "babel"
}`

Comment: ESLint is the troublemaker

Comment: For now I set `"eslint.enable": false,` to prevent `.js` files to ne bot formatted by ESLint, but this is not a valid solution

Comment: `"eslint.quotes" = ["error", "double", { "allowTemplateLiterals": true }]`