# Configure Prettier to avoid replacing quotes

Tags: javascript, lint, prettier, lit-html, lit

**Background**

I have tried several keywords but was not able to find a solution to disable prettier's quotes modification.
I am working on a Polymer Lit project and I have tried a lot of things but it is really hard to maintain the code indentation ...
So prettier does a very good job but only one problem which breaks my code.

**Code Before Formatting**

```js
html`<div style="${'background-color: ' + this.bgColor }">
...
</div>`
```

**Code After Formatting**

```js
html`<div style="${"background-color: " + this.bgColor}">...</div>`
```

Is there any flag / property I can pass to prettier to ignore or avoid the quotes and all the other things should work out ...

If there isn't can anyone tell me if there is any other Formater that does a clean job with lit element ..

Comment: Do you have any config file including rules ?

Comment: nope ... I am using vs code extension ... I think that supports all the settings though through configuration file ...

Comment: If you know any prop that disables that thing which it does with quotes .. let me know I can create config

Comment: Hope you find your response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53621884/15288641).

Comment: @yousoumar thank you for response sir but that's between choosing single and double quotes .. but I want it to leave the quotes be ..

Comment: is this code in js file ? And can you share your editor config ? @anees

Comment: yes the code is in js file ... the current piece of code is inside the LitElement class ... and my editor Config is default ... except I am using prettier as default formatter for js files.

Comment: Why are you saying this "breaks" your code? The two snippets you've shown are absolutely equivalent, they should both work. Still, if you prefer single over double quotes in your JS strings, [there's a prettier option for that](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quotes)

Comment: @Bergi inside the style attributes you see it converts the single quotes to double quotes which make the style attribute result only to `${` ..

Comment: @anees No, they don't? `${}` in a tagged template literal takes precedence over any quotes. Are you just confused by broken syntax highlighting?

Comment: @Bergi wow ... Actually I never tried building it ... because I never saved the file after the formatting because synatx highlighting was broken  ... and I didn't know that first template literals will evaluate then the rest and it will not break ...

Comment: @Bergi thank you for pointing out that .. I will try it see ... (even if it works it is going to be a lot more confusing and a lot less readable ...)

Comment: An alternative solution that doesn't have to do with prettier would be just not using the first pair of quotes, when binding using lit, you can do just this `style=${'color:' + color}`. Source: https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#attribute-expressions

Answer (score 3):

This is my `.prettierrc` for all my lit projects:

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "bracketSpacing": false,
  "arrowParens": "always"
}
```

And in markup I am using this (example):

```
<div class="wrapper ${this.animated ? 'active' : ''}" ${animate()}>
```

That works for me and never had any problems.