# Is there a shortcut to change both quotes enclosing a string?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example:

`const greet = 'Hello!'`

I want to change the single-quotes to double-quotes...

`const greet = "Hello!"`

...where I just select/highlight the first single-quote and overwrite it with a double-quote and automatically have the closing single-quote changed as well?

I mean, I could do a selection on the first single-quote then `Ctrl+Shift+L`, which will show multiple cursors that will allow me to do it, but it does it for all the single-quotes. I only want it done on a single string or that one line only.

Is there a shortcut for this? (something like `editor.linkedEditing` setting)

Comment: Possible duplicate for the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864985/vscode-single-to-double-quote-automatic-replace

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather The link you posted actually talks about the opposite and is describing a problem about something that is unexpected

Comment: select the first quote, then `Ctrl+D`

Comment: @rioV8 Exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @JP_ OK my friend. Well, I only said "a possible duplicate". Glad that you have got your answer :) Cheers !!!

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Yep, that's why I also corrected you about the link you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the first quote, then `Ctrl+D`

Thanks to @rioV8!

Comment: Does not work on MacOs