# VSCode single or double quote to backticks automatice replace

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I want to use only backticks.
I want that every time I click save, the formatter will change all my quotes type to backticks. I tried the built-in VSCode formatter for JS and prettier, and I didn't see this setting. I prefer the build-in formatter.

I also tried some extensions, but the automatic the replace only after pressing `${,`  but I want it to be replaced always.

You can see this question:
[VSCode single to double quote automatic replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864985/vscode-single-to-double-quote-automatic-replace)

There is not settings for backtick, only single or double.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at this a little bit, it seems like [Prettier decided not to implement this feature](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/54).

[`dprint-plugin-typescript`](https://github.com/dprint/dprint-plugin-typescript/issues/345) supports this, but not sure about the default VSCode formatter.

You can, however, enforce this as an ESLint rule [as seen here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes) by

1. adding `"quotes": ["backtick"]` to your `.eslintrc`
2. run `eslint --fix`.

I assume there is a way to automate this on save document, format document, etc..