# The concatenation is not working for this line of code

Tags: javascript, concatenation, backticks

```
let userName = "Kunaal";
let age = 30;
```

//My name is Kunaal and I am 30 years old//

```
let text = "My name is ${userName} and I am ${age} years old";
console.log(text);
```

Expected Output:

My name is Kunaal and I am 30 years old.

Actual Output:

My name is ${userName} and I am ${age} years old.

Comment: You literally put "backticks" in as a tag, but you're clearly not using them.

Comment: I did not get it, can you please explain.

Comment: I actually used backticks in the VS code but as soon as I am right clicking the backticks are converting into double quotes and hence the output.

Comment: @KunaalKansotia you can use concatenation dont use `${}` use this 
`let text = "My name is "+userName+ "and I am "+age +" years old";`

Comment: if you click the backticks are converted into double quotes right away maybe [configure prettier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864985/vscode-single-to-double-quote-automatic-replace)

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks (``) don't use double quotes ("") in your variable `text`:

[Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> In JavaScript, string interpolation is done using backticks ``` (``) ``` and the `${}` syntax.

```js
let userName = "Kunaal";
let age = 30;

//My name is Kunaal and I am 30 years old//

let text = `My name is ${userName} and I am ${age} years old`;
console.log(text);
```

Comment: SORTED. Thank you for your answers everyone 

Comment: @KunaalKansotia I am here to help you at any time