# How to apply single quotes in Vue templates in a Nuxt3 project using Prettier?

Tags: prettier, nuxt3, single-quotes

I know this is an older question, but I still haven't found a solution.

In my Nuxt3 project, I want to use single quotes in all Vue templates. If there are nested layers, I prefer single quotes to enclose double quotes.

#### Below are my settings related to the question:

// package.json

```
{

  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write '**/*.{js,ts,vue}'",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.js,.vue ."
},
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
  }
}
```

// user > setting.json

```
{
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true
}
```

// .eslintrc.cjs

```
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { singleQuote: true }],
  },
```

// .prettierrc

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

#### These are the methods that I've found on StackOverflow.

I've tried them all. However, none of them worked for me.

1. Cmd + Shift + P > Format Document With … > Prettier - Code formatter
2. **Code** > **Preferences** > **Settings**, then look for **Quote**, select **Prettier** and check both boxes (**Prettier: JSX single quote & Prettier: single quote**) *Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53621884/22782380*
3. Disable the Volar extension

If anyone has more recent methods to achieve this, please let me know. Thank you.