# I have set eslint single quotes with .eslintrc.cjs. But when i save file vscode auto change to double quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

This is my .eslintrc.cjs

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint-config-react-app',
    'react-app',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  plugins: ['import'],
  rules: {
    quotes: [2, 'single'],
  },
  "globals": {
    "React": "readonly"
  }
}
```

and vscode settings.json

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
  }
```

test.js

```
export const Utils = {
  isFunction: function (it: any) {
    return toString.call(it) === '[object Function]';
  },
```

But when i save test.js,  vscode auto change to double quotes. Why!!!

Comment: You can your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864985/vscode-single-to-double-quote-automatic-replace

Comment: thanks, it must cooperate with Prettier

Comment: There is any way to fix it when i save in vscode and not use Prettier

Comment: I remove settings "editor.formatOnSave": true can solve， but i have new problem the indet not auto fix when i use --fix command, but i save one file can auto fix this problem

Comment: Either disabled prettier, change your prettier settings, or use the prettier ESLint rules to enforce those settings instead of your custom quote settings